# Delete questions with answers linking to other posts?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

Just posted a question, which was swiftly answered by someone linking a different post.  See the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815563/android-mail-client-popup-in-app).

It's clearly a duplicate (as the linked post answered the original question) and could be deleted for that reason.

On the other hand, I was unsure of how to phrase my queries to find the actual answer, and the post serves some value to redirect future users with the same problem.

Should it be deleted?

Comment: What you can do is flag the post as duplicate. You will then have a button on top of your question that says "Accept this duplicate" (or something). Once you click it, the question will be marked as duplicate.

Comment: _Tthis post being marked as a duplicate is 2meta4me..._